# What's with these g++ "multiple definition" errors?

Tags: c++, winapi, makefile, g++, mingw

I'm in the early stages (read:just started yesterday) of a project, and I'm setting up my initial makefile. It's very simplistic. Here's the full contents of the file:

```
all: main.o resource.o
    g++ -o output.exe main.o resource.o

main.o: main.cpp main.h resource.h
    g++ -mwindows -o main.o main.cpp

resource.o: resource.rc
    windres resource.rc resource.o

clean:
    rm *.o
```

At this point I think it's important to mention that I'm working on Windows, so I'm doing all of this in either Powershell with MinGW g++ 4.5.2 or else with Cygwin and g++ 3.4.4 (I've tried both; same errors).

Without printing the contents of all the above-listed files, it suffices to say that main.h contains a reference to windows.h and resource.h, main.cpp contains a reference to main.h and a few functions, most importantly an int WINAPI WinMain(...) function and an LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(...) function, resource.rc contains resource definition statements for a simple menubar with a file menu and a dummy second menu as well as a reference to resource.h, and resource.h simply contains #define statements for the IDs used in resource.rc.

Now, I can compile both resource.rc and main.h separately from each other and get those two nice .o files. However, when I try to link them and produce output.exe, I get the following scary list of errors, none of which I really understand:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x160): first defined here
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../crt2.o:crt1.c:(.text+0x140): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The above is generated in Powershell. Cygwin gives a very similar list of errors, still centering around "multiple definition" statements. The multiple definitions seem to be originating in C:/mingw/lib/crt2.o, and possibly another file named crt1.c, which would seem to be more helpful since obviously C is far more human readable than a .o file, but I can't find anything with that title anywhere within the C:\MinGW folder.

Any direction at all would be helpful, because at the moment I'm pretty lost.

EDIT:
The only #include statement in main.cpp:

```
#include "main.h"
```

The contents of main.h:

```
#ifndef _MAIN_H_
    #define _MAIN_H_

    #include <windows.h>
    #include "resource.h"

#endif
```

Comment: Perhaps it would help to see the first part of the main.cpp file where headers are being included.  I recall having a problem similar to this that was resolved by understanding that one of the headers I explicitly included needed to be included implicitly by another header file, so that the `#define`'s got set correctly.

Comment: Don't use the leading underscore with `_MAIN_H_`. Names with leading underscores are reserved for libraries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing the `-c` argument to g++ when you're compiling a .cpp file to an .o file . As it is now , you're trying to create one executable from another one.

`g++ -mwindows -o main.o main.cpp` should be `g++ -mwindows -c -o main.o main.cpp`

While at it, add warning flags as well, at least `-Wall`

Comment: Good call, but it didn't help.

Comment: @KenB did you `make clean` before trying?

Comment: Oh my word. I feel like an idiot. That did it. Thanks, to both of you.

Comment: I hit the same errors. Would you please tell me where to add above things if I am using CMakelist to create codeblock project with mingw.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling your main `int main(...)` instead of `int WINAPI WinMain(...)`? As far as I remember MinGW had its own WinMain calling main

**[edit]**

That is, try changing `int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)` to `int main(int argc, char **argv)` in your main.cpp

Comment: How would I reference the WinMain arguments? Remember WinMain is constructed thusly:


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){...}

Comment: @KenB Are this arguments being used in the WinMain?

Comment: Yes. This is a simple Win32 API program.

Comment: The above adjusment prevents main.cpp from being compiled.